# list to csv with = in the list

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I had a requirement to scan the logs and identify the specific keywords and then export that to a csv or to a database

I was able to achieve half of the solution. so far I was able to scan the logs with specific key word get that line and then in that line pick only necessary details and put it to a list
what I am unable to do is put this list into a desired format in csv

list is looking like below after half part of solution

```
['batchName=ColVal Batch', 'countOfOutboundXmlSent=183', 'countOfTradesPersistedInTdx=193', 'batchStartTime=2023-04-27T09:43:51.208Z]
```

desired output in csv
[image: desired output in csv]

```
t1 = open(r"C:\Temp\tntrreporting.log", 'r')
fileone = t1.readlines()
text = "BatchTriggerDetails"
for line in fileone:
    if text in (line):
        details_index = line.find("batchName")
        details_content = (line[details_index:len(line)-2])
        details_1= details_content.split(",")
        print (details_1)
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, would you post a sample of original file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the others that the input data should be included, maybe this could help.

```
import pandas as pd
d = ['batchName=ColVal Batch', 'countOfOutboundXmlSent=183', 'countOfTradesPersistedInTdx=193', 'batchStartTime=2023-04-27T09:43:51.208Z']
d = {i.split("=")[0]: i.split("=")[1] for i in d}
d = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
d.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

[image]